# Performance of element-compare in java collections

Tags: java, performance, collections

**Problem:**

Given two `Collection<?>`s, check if both contain the same elements.

- Assuming that the actual implementation of the collection is unknown
- Assuming that the elements do not occur in the same order
- Assuming that no element does occur twice in the same collection

**Solution 1:**

```
boolean equals = c1.containsAll(c2) && c2.containsAll(c1);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
boolean equals = new HashSet<?>(c1).equals(new HashSet<?>(c2));
```

I would assume **Solution 2** to be more efficient (*O(n)*) than **Solution 1** (*O(n^2)*).

Am I correct or did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Big O complexity of these is correct, Solution 1 involves iterating over one list (`O (n)`) for each item in the other list, which is `O (n^2)`.  Solution 2 involves two `O (n)` copies and iterating over one set (`O (n)`) and doing `O (1)` `.contains()` checks on the other set.  All told, that's just `O (n)`.

But depending on your constraints you can do better (not asymptotically better, just a better implementation).

- Since we're assuming no duplicate elements, there's no need to do the second `.containsAll()` check.  Simply check they're the same size (which might be `O (n)`, but it's still better than duplicating an `O (n^2)` check) then do the `.containsAll()`.
- There's no need to convert `c2` into a `Set`, since it will be iterated over anyways; just convert `c1` and use `.containsAll()`.
- You can use `instanceof Set` to test if `c1` or `c2` is already a `Set`, and use that object's `.containsAll()` method; this will run in `O (n)` time even if the other object is not a set, and avoids the copying overhead that Solution 2 has.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of the size comparison. Good answer.

Comment: Truth is _not_ optimized for this sort of thing, and in fact may perform significantly worse.  Truth is a _testing library_ and should not be used in performance critical code.  (Speaking from a room sitting with the Truth maintainers.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for the insight, I've removed the Truth plug.  I'd assumed Truth's fluent design would make such optimizations easy, but clearly I shouldn't assume.  Since Truth can't assume arbitrary Collections contain no duplicate elements, it can't safely assimilate them into Sets.

Comment: @user902383 I don't understand your point.  A `List` is not equal to a `Set`, even if they contain the same elements.  If you want to compare the contents of two `Collection`s, you must either use `.containsAll()` or ensure they are the same collection type before using `.equals()`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by dimo414, in general, yes. But you can always do better (not asymptotically better, just faster). And it gets more complicated:

```
if (c1.size() != c2.size()) {
    return false;
} else if (c1 instanceof Set) {
    return c1.containsAll(c2);
} else if (c2 instanceof Set) {
    return c2.containsAll(c1);
} else {
    return new HashSet<>(c1).containsAll(c2);
}
```

And there are collections having slow `size`, which you may want to handle specially...